# Val_acc doesn't increse

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a model with transfer learning, mobilenetv2, but my val accurary stops incressing at around 0,60. I've tried to train the top layers that I've build, after that I've tried to also train some of the mobilenets layers. Same result. How can I fix it? I have to mention that I am new to deep learning and I am not sure that the top layers I've build are right. Feel free to correct me.

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_data_dir = "/content/FER2013/Training"
validation_data_dir = "/content/FER2013/PublicTest"


datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    validation_split=0)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

```
IMG_SHAPE = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)

base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
```

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   base_model,
  
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])
```

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-5), #I've tried with .Adam as well
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.9, patience=3)
```

```
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=6, mode='auto')
```

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('/content/weights.hd5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
```

```
epochs = 50
learning_rate = 0.004 #I've tried other values as well
```

```
history_fine = model.fit(train_generator, 
                         steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), 
                         epochs=epochs, 
                         callbacks=[lr_reducer, checkpointer, early_stopper],
                         validation_data=val_generator, 
                         validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

```
Epoch 1/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7362 - accuracy: 0.2929
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 1.58818, saving model to /content/weights.hd5
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/tracking.py:111: Model.state_updates (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as updates are applied automatically.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/tracking.py:111: Layer.updates (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as updates are applied automatically.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/weights.hd5/assets
448/448 [==============================] - 166s 370ms/step - loss: 1.7362 - accuracy: 0.2929 - val_loss: 1.5882 - val_accuracy: 0.4249
Epoch 2/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3852 - accuracy: 0.4664
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 1.58818 to 1.31690, saving model to /content/weights.hd5
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/weights.hd5/assets
448/448 [==============================] - 165s 368ms/step - loss: 1.3852 - accuracy: 0.4664 - val_loss: 1.3169 - val_accuracy: 0.4827
Epoch 3/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2058 - accuracy: 0.5277
Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 1.31690 to 1.21979, saving model to /content/weights.hd5
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/weights.hd5/assets
448/448 [==============================] - 165s 368ms/step - loss: 1.2058 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.2198 - val_accuracy: 0.5271
Epoch 4/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0828 - accuracy: 0.5861
Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 1.21979 to 1.18972, saving model to /content/weights.hd5
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/weights.hd5/assets
448/448 [==============================] - 166s 370ms/step - loss: 1.0828 - accuracy: 0.5861 - val_loss: 1.1897 - val_accuracy: 0.5533
Epoch 5/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9754 - accuracy: 0.6380
Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 1.18972 to 1.13336, saving model to /content/weights.hd5
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/weights.hd5/assets
448/448 [==============================] - 165s 368ms/step - loss: 0.9754 - accuracy: 0.6380 - val_loss: 1.1334 - val_accuracy: 0.5743
Epoch 6/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.8761 - accuracy: 0.6848
Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 1.13336
448/448 [==============================] - 153s 342ms/step - loss: 0.8761 - accuracy: 0.6848 - val_loss: 1.1348 - val_accuracy: 0.5882
Epoch 7/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7783 - accuracy: 0.7264
Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 1.13336
448/448 [==============================] - 153s 341ms/step - loss: 0.7783 - accuracy: 0.7264 - val_loss: 1.1392 - val_accuracy: 0.5893
Epoch 8/50
448/448 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6832 - accuracy: 0.7638
Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 1.13336
448/448 [==============================] - 153s 342ms/step - loss: 0.6832 - accuracy: 0.7638 - val_loss: 1.1542 - val_accuracy: 0.6052
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a classic case of overfitting is not on-topic or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Since your validation loss is increasing while your training loss decreases, I think you may have a problem of overfitting to your training sets. Some things that could help are:

- Use less dense layers. I think there are too many, but I could be wrong since I don't know what problem you are solving.
- Add dropout layers after every dense layer.
- Increase the dropout rates.
- Use data augmentation on your training set (since you are already using ImageDataGenerator it won't be that hard).
- Reduce the number of neurons in dense layers.
- Use regularization.

You can try applying any of them or multiple of them at the same time. Tweaking your model is a lot of trial and error, do some experiments, and keep the model that achieves the best performance.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try. I want to build an facial express recognition model

Comment: I think that the best approach would be to add only one dense layer after MobileNet with like 128~512 neurons and ReLU activation followed by the output layer (7 neurons and softmax activation). If you achieve the performance you want, then you are done. Otherwise, increase the number of neurons or add a new hidden layer. If you start overfitting again try adding dropout after dense layers. If at some point your training accuracy stops increasing even though you keep adding layers, you'll probably need to introduce greater changes in the model architecture.

Answer (score 0):

With your training loss decreasing and your validation loss increasing it appears that you are in an over fitting situation. The more complex your model the higher the chance of this happening so I suggest you try to simplify your model. Try removing all the dense layers except for the top layer which is producing your classifications. Run that and see how it does. My experience with MobileNet  is that it should work well. If not add an additional dense layer  with about 128 neurons followed by a drop out layer. Use the drop out value to adjust for over fitting. If you are still over fitting you might want to consider adding regularizers to this dense layer. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/) It could also be the case that you need more training samples. Use the Image Data Generator to augment your data set. For example set horizontal_flip-True. I notice you did not include the MobileNetV2 pre-processing function in the Image Data Generator. I believe this is necessary  so modify the code as shown below.  I have also found I get the best results with MobileNet if I train the entire model. So before you compile your model add the code below.

```
ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=True
```

As an aside you can delete that layer in you model and within the MobileNet set the parameter pooling='max'. I see you start out with a very small learning rate try something like .005. Since you have the ReduceLROnPlateau callback this will adjust it if it is to large but will allow you to converge faster.

Comment: Thank you. I start doing what you sugested, now I am waiting to train. But I didn't understand what you said here " As an aside you can delete that layer in you model and within the MobileNet set the parameter pooling='max'." can you please explain like for dummies

Comment: Sure. Mobilenet has a parameter pooling. With top=False you can set pooling='avg' and it adds an average pooling layer as the output. You added that layer separately which is fine. It was just an FYI.